# Sed Command delete before first instance and after last

Tags: xml, text-manipulation

I'm looking for a sed command to clean up some kml files I have.  The files are all on a single line and look like this

```
<some text><kml><Document><name> Name </name><Placemark><name> Hotel 01 </name></Placemark><Placemark><name> Hotel 02 </name></Placemark><Placemark><name> Hotel 03 </name></Placemark></Document></kml>
```

Ideally I want the only the parts starting with (and including) the first `<Placemark>` element to the last (and including) `</Placemark>` element and these sections from all the kml files output to a single file.

I'd be happy with a command to either delete all text before the first `<Placemark>` and delete all text after last `</Placemark>`, or a command to extract the content after the first `<Placemark>` and before the last `</Placemark>`.

A command that I've managed to botch together so far is:

```
find . -name 'kmlFiles00*' -exec sed -r 's/^.{879}/ /' {} \; | sed -e 's/<\/Document><\/kml>//g' > placemarks_`date +%d-%m-%Y`.list
```

which has worked in getting rid of the first 879 characters and then removing all the instances of `</Document></kml>` before outputting it all into final file, but this is pretty messy so I'm looking for a cleaner command. I have also tried

```
sed -e 's/^.*<Placemark> //' -e 's/<\/Placemark>.*$//'
```

Which I know is getting closer but still fails

Answer (score 2):

```sh
awk NF=NF FPAT='<Placemark>.*</Placemark>'
```

- define a field as being `<Placemark>.*</Placemark>`
- [force rebuild](http://gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html) of the line, printing all fields

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/<Placemark>/\n&/;s/.*\n(.*<\/Placemark>).*/\1/' file
```